How to draw vertical line on a chart on a time yaxis
I use a C# chart to show the sea tides over the time of days.
I want to mark the actual time by a vertical line.
It works well with
private void VerticalLine()
{    
    double MyDate = DateTime.Now.ToOADate();

    double maxDataPoint = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum;
    double minDataPoint = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum;

    LineAnnotation annotation = new LineAnnotation();
    annotation.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
    annotation.AxisX = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    annotation.AxisY = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    annotation.AnchorY = minDataPoint;
    annotation.Height = maxDataPoint - minDataPoint; ;
    annotation.Width = 0;
    annotation.LineWidth = 1;
    annotation.StartCap = LineAnchorCapStyle.None;
    annotation.EndCap = LineAnchorCapStyle.None;
    annotation.AnchorX = MyDate;  // <- your point
    annotation.LineColor = Color.Red; // <- your color
    chart.Annotations.Add(annotation);
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VerticalLine();
}

but when I connect VerticalLine() to a timer
it produces multiple vertical lines over the time.
How can I avoid this?

If it works well without a timer, then don't add a timer.

This question has nothing to do with lines, let alone vertical lines; it does not even have anything to do with charts, let alone with chart axes; this is a question about how to achieve an animation.

Welcome to the wonderful world of programming.  Copying and pasting sample code (as evidenced by the // <- your point and // <- your color comments) is only going to get you so far; you need to actually understand what the code does in order to use it effectively.
You might think you can achieve working programs by asking everything one question at a time on stack overflow, but this severely underestimates the number of questions you are going to have. On the grand scale of things, it will not work. So, you have to use Dr. Spock's favorite tool: this rare and elusive thing called "Logic".
So, you see lines being added to your chart, but not removed. And then you look at your code, and you see a chart.Annotations.Add() operation, but no corresponding .Remove() operation. See the connection?
Alternatively, if the .AnchorX property can be updated, (which I do not know, and I can't be bothered to look up right now,) you might want to invoke .Add() only once, keep a reference to the added annotation somewhere, and then from within your timer tick method simply keep updating the .AnchorX property instead of adding a whole new annotation.

Mike Nakis,Thank you for the hints. It works now correctly, with "chart.Annotations.Remove(annotation); VerticalLine();" inside timer_Tick.
